# GeForce8800 ultra

Tags: 10.04

I have been running Ubuntu 10.04 with GeForce 8800 Ultra graphics card without any problems for many months until a few days ago, after some updates, everything stopped working.  Can't use Stellarium (my favorite program) and everything (even the mousecusor)  stops responding for a long time. Takes ages to load the desktop and everything is just "f..."  B.t.w. I have a dual boot and WinXP is not having this problem with the 8800 card.  So, elementary... What's going on between Ubuntu and Nvidia?

Best regards
Gunnar

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with nvidia drivers after updates, installing the driver again from nvidia.com solved the problem every time for me, so you might want to take a look at that.

Comment: I have tried to update from nvidia.com but the site does not respond, says it cannot find my graphics card and stops.  I believe that some ubuntu kernel upgrades are the root of this problem, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Weird, i just went there and it worked, this is the [link](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/295.40/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.40.run) for 32bit and [here's](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.40/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.40.run) 64bit link

Comment: I ran this:sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current   but get the message: This driver is active but not in use  :(

Comment: Just download the installer from nvidia

Comment: Maybe the problem has been found:? http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA4ODQ   So we wait for awhile for some patches/ solutions from Nvidia